# Analytics function is not allowed in Group By

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join

I have a following query:

```
SELECT t.date, 
t.transactionId,
t.channelGrouping, 
tp.itemRevenue,
t.transactionItemQuantity, 
t.company, 
t.campaign, 
ifnull(replace((regexp_extract(tp.productCategory, r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.&;+ -]+)")),"&amp;", "&"), "N/A") as productCategory,
ifnull(sum(a.adCost),0) as adCost
FROM `kpi.TransactionsByChannel` t left join kpi.TransactionProducts tp
on tp.transactionId = t.transactionId
left join kpi.Ads a
on a.company = t.company and a.date = t.date and a.campaign = t.campaign group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

which returns me result:

[image]

However, as you can see, adCost is not correct and duplicated. I need to get ratio of it based on itemRevenue or just write first row and other rows should be 0.

I tried following query:

```
SELECT t.date, 
t.transactionId,
t.channelGrouping, 
tp.itemRevenue,
t.transactionItemQuantity, 
t.company, 
t.campaign, 
ifnull(replace((regexp_extract(tp.productCategory, r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.&;+ -]+)")),"&amp;", "&"), "N/A") as productCategory,
round(adCost*(itemRevenue/SUM(itemRevenue) over (partition by tp.company, tp.productCategory, tp.date)),2) as adCost_adjusted,
FROM kpi.TransactionsByChannel t left join kpi.TransactionProducts tp
on tp.transactionId = t.transactionId
left join kpi.Ads a
on a.company = t.company and a.date = t.date and a.campaign = t.campaign group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

but I am getting an error of:

```
Column 9 contains an analytic function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY at [13:99]
```

Any helps would be really appreciated!

Comment: You can not `GROUP BY` a `SUM()`. The whole point of analytic functions is to calculate something over the group of rows selected by `GROUP BY`. What is the desired result?

Comment: Just remove the column where you inserted `SUM()` from your `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Kaii But I want to get the ratio of revenue and divide the ad cost based on that. To calculate this, I need sum. How I should sort it out?

Comment: @Kaii desired result is:

Instead of repeating adCost 4 times (63.87), to divide 63.87 into 4 based on the revenue ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this approach:

```
with ttr as
(
    select 
        t.transactionId,
        sum(tp.itemRevenue) as TotalItemRevenue
    from 
        `kpi.TransactionsByChannel` t 
    inner join 
        kpi.TransactionProducts tp
    on 
        tp.transactionId = t.transactionId
    group by 
        t.transactionId
)

SELECT 
    t.date, 
    t.transactionId,
    t.channelGrouping, 
    tp.itemRevenue,
    t.transactionItemQuantity, 
    t.company, 
    t.campaign, 
    ifnull(replace((regexp_extract(tp.productCategory, r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.&;+ -]+)")),"&amp;", "&"), "N/A") as productCategory,
    ifnull(a.adCost,0) * tp.itemRevenue / ttr.TotalItemRevenue as adCost_adjusted
FROM 
    `kpi.TransactionsByChannel` t 
inner join
    ttr
on
    t.transactionId = ttr.transactionId
inner join 
    kpi.TransactionProducts tp
on 
    tp.transactionId = t.transactionId
left join 
    kpi.Ads a
on 
    a.company = t.company
    and a.date = t.date 
    and a.campaign = t.campaign
```